# DRY in django url

Tags: django, url, dry

```
                   url( r'^category/(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<slug>.+)/$',
                        views.readers.category,
                        name='category',
                        ),

                   url( r'^category/(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<slug>.+)/guide/$',
                        views.readers.category_guide,
                        name='category_guide',
                        )
```

You could probably see the above two urls share big chunk in the format.
Is there a good way to factor them out?

Comment: Can't you use only one of the two(id/slug) in the url because they should be unique or at least one of them should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex is just a string, so you could extract the base string and append what you need.

```
base = r'^category/(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<slug>.+)/'

url(base + '$',
    views.readers.category,
    name='category',
),

url(base + 'guide/$',
    views.readers.category_guide,
    name='category_guide',
)
```